# Project stopped running at Windows XP (32-bit)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing an application for a friend. I use Visual Basic 2012 (64-bit) and Windows 7 (64-bit).
I took a demo down to him to try it out to see what more features he wanted, and it was running ok.

When I got back the next week after implementing the new features, it refused to run on any of his Windows XP (32-bit) machines.
Error code:

```
MyApplicationName.exe is not a valid Win32 application
```

I tried it at a computer running Windows 7 (32-bit) which still worked all fine.

So, any ideas why it suddenly stopped running?

Comment: Difficult to say without looking at your code, but have you compiled your application using the settings for AnyCPU or x86 platforms?

Comment: I had a look at the settings, it's set at "Any CPU" and Prefer 32-bit is also enabled.

I could link the code, I'll add it in a sec...

Comment: Posting such a long code is pretty much unacceptable: nobody will read it. Please trim it down to the necessary minimum to reproduce the problem. Actually, going from your error description, the error isn’t in your code at all but rather in your project settings. Investigate those. And see whether your friend maybe got his PC downgraded from a 64 bit system to a 32 bit system.

Comment: My friend hardly uses his computer. I'm quite sure nothing has changed there. And I didn't really touch the project settings at all since the last time we tested when it worked fine.

I'll add the suspected function above...

Comment: Nothing in the code you’ve posted is incompatible with 32 bits. I highly doubt that *anything* in your code is – and that, even if it were, you’d get such an error message.

Comment: Is there a way I could share my project settings easily?

Comment: Judging from the error message then your application is stopped even before reaching the first line of your code. Something in your project references is wrong (a reference to a 64bit dll?) or perhaps you could try to compile for x86 Platform and check if something changes

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you receive? Also, to debug, try setting the PE header flags in your executable to 32Bit only by running Corflags.exe on it (Corflags.exe your.exe /32BITREQ+)

Comment: I can try google it until I find it. My friends computer is nowhere nearby atm. so I can't really re-produce it =/
I'll do my best to find it

Comment: I'm quite sure this error message is more or less the exact same as I got:

MyApplicationName.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Still I suggest to change your target Platform to pure x86. In this way, if you have some reference to 64bit dll it is possible that your app will fail in 64bit machines, but you have the debugger and more info at your disposition

Comment: So, how do I do that? I can't find anything like that in the settings.

Comment: Only .NET frameworks up to version 4.0 are supported on XP, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

VS2012 will not generate an EXE that can run on XP when you use the default project settings.  What matters is the .NET Framework version you target.  If that's version 4.5 then there are *two* problems.

First one is that .NET 4.5 is not available for XP.  Second one is important for this exception message, the compiler will mark the version of Windows that's required to run the EXE in the file header.  That version number has always been set to 4.00.  Until VS2012, it is now set to 6.00, the version number of Vista.  XP will instantly reject your EXE with the "is not a valid Win32 application" message, even before it will tell you that it doesn't have .NET 4.5 installed.

Fix your problem by targeting .NET 4.0 or earlier.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Target framework setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using corflags with /32bit+ and see if it works.

More information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx

Comment: Please don't post links that are specific to ancient versions of .NET unless the answer is specific to that version.